# Converting Phone String to Integer In Javascript

Tags: javascript, parseint

I am attempting to convert a phone number string into an integer by using parseInt but only receiving the first 3 digits in return and then I would like to add all of the integers of each phone number. Here is my code:

```
var largest_phone_number = [];
largest_phone_number.push("415-215-2561", "312-367-6721", "345-876-5467");


for(var i=0; i<largest_phone_number.length; i++) {
var number = parseInt(largest_phone_number[i]);
  console.log(number);
}
```

Comment: Phone numbers are _not_ actually numbers; trying to convert them into integers makes no sense whatsoever, Treat them as what they are – strings.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you elaborate on what exactly you're trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `parseInt` will convert up to the first character that's not convertible, hence 3 digits. You could start by stripping out non-numbers with regex first, then do a `parseInt`. Don't forget the radix for `parseInt`. You wouldn't want to end up with an octal.

```
var phoneNumbers = largest_phone_number.map(function(number){
  return parseInt(number.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''), 10);
});
// [4152152561, 3123676721, 3458765467]
```

Some tips for phone numbers:

- There are phone numbers whose area code starts with `0`. `parseInt` will disregard leading zeroes. Essentially, you just lost information.
- There are phone numbers that have these symbols `+()-` as well as spaces. They will differ in different parts of the world.
- It's best to keep phone numbers as strings. Why? Refer to bullets 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could first remove the dash

```js
var largest_phone_number = [];
largest_phone_number.push("415-215-2561", "312-367-6721", "345-876-5467");


for(var i=0; i<largest_phone_number.length; i++) {
  var number = parseInt(largest_phone_number[i].replace(/-/g,''));
  console.log(number);
}
```